# Google Drive: can multiple people move files into a shared folder for the owner to view privately?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

The teaching assistant for one of my graduate school courses wants students to submit homework assignments by adding each doc to one of his shared folders in Google Drive. However, it would be preferable if only he could then view the submissions.  Do you have any suggestions for accommodating this situation?

Comment: If the folder is shared, than everyone with access with at least be able to view all contents. One way around this is to have all students share their files with the aid, instead of uploading into a folder.

Comment: This script/form combo is what I used to do something similar. http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/